# CartThrob payment issue

Tags: cartthrob, payment-gateway, subscriptions

On a client site which was working fine until recently we are now hitting an issue where an error is being returned before sending the user to our payment gateway:

> Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) (77)

Any thoughts on the root cause of this issue and how might be able to resolve?
The payment gateway we are using in this instance is SagePay (offsite).

Cheers

Cole

Comment: try to restart server

Answer (score 2):

The most simple solution in case like this:

**Reboot the server.**